# Moving from md5 to PBKDF2 how to?

Tags: php, mysql, security, php-5.3, pbkdf2

I need to upgrade md5 based simple authentication module to [PBKDF2](https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm#phpsourcecode) ,and I am looking for possible schema and extra steps and flow of operation and required changes for following:

a. New user account creation
      Old one is simplest one : password=md5(password)

b. Password Reset

curently:

```
update authtable set password=md5(newpassword) where password=md5(oldpwd)
and username='usernamexyz';
```

c. Authentication

```
 select id, username from authtable where password=md5(pwd) and username='usernamexyz';
```

schema:

```
  CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username` varchar(60) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `password` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,  
  `email` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

I don't see any tutorial /article on how to implement , the db schema concerns , the password/salt length in database etc .. relating to PBKDF2. I might have missed it , please give a reference.

Could someone shed light on these dark corners on how to implementing PBKDF2 using php/mysql.

Since I am using php 5.3, I will not be able to use the [build-in PBKDF2](http://php.net/manual/en/function.hash-pbkdf2.php) function (i.e it required php 5.5 atleast).

Answer (score 2):

To upgrade, you have to add new column where you will store passwords hashed by pbkdf2. This will be initially empty. Then do these changes:

a. PHP: `$password_pbkdf2 = create_hash($password)`. SQL: `password_pbkdf2 = '$password_pbkdf2', password = ''`

b. Authentication as in c. Then setting password as in a.

c. SQL: `select password, password_pbkdf2 where username='usernamexyz'`

```
PHP:
if($password_pbkdf2) {
  if(validate_password($submitted_password, $password_pbkdf2) === false) {
    die('wrong username/pw');
  }
} elseif($password === md5($submitted_password)) {
  // do a. with $submitted_password
} else {
  die('wrong username/pw');
}
```

Comment: do we need password at all in db now ? I suspect that hash string has all info as format: algorithm:iterations:salt:hash

Comment: if you notice only hashed password is stored